# How do you handle APIKeys?

Tags: flutter, dart, security

I am developing an app using Flutter, but I am unsure how to handle API keys. If I don't use environment variables, I have to write the API key directly in AppDelegate.swift or AndroidManifest.xml. However, it is said that using environment variables for API keys is insecure from a security standpoint.

However, while it is often mentioned that using environment variables for API keys is insecure from a security standpoint, there is no specific solution provided anywhere.

In the end, how should an API key be properly included in a Flutter app?

Comment: Is this static application or do you have any backend code as well? Also tell us, if you are using GCP or AWS or anything else in your application

Comment: It will be an application that interacts with GCP.

Comment: Did you checked  Firebase Remote Config?

Comment: Secret Manager don’t include APIKeys client side

Answer (score 1):

I Assume that you are talking about Google API key,

So yes, saving/storing the API key in the environment variable is not secure, since you can easily decrypt the package and get the API key string.

But, to use the Google API key, you need to sign your APK with your Keystore and use your precise package name (com.company.appid).

So that means, even though someone got your Google API key from your APK, they can't do much about it. Since they need to sign their APK with your Keystore to use that API key.

And back to the warning. The warning about not using API Key on the environment is meant to be a general warning, not specific to Google api keys.

For example, that would be dangerous if you stored your api key from openai chat, since someone could easily get that api key and use the api with that, since that key don't have any restriction that Google's api keys have.

To secure the secret key, you can create some backend implementation that can call the api with that secret key. So instead of putting the secret key on the client side (mobile app) you can put the secret key on the backend, where it is nearly impossible to get the secret key without having access to the server. And you can create your own api to call open ai api.

It kind like this.

client => backend (with secret key) => openAI API => backend => client.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Indeed, I asked the question with Google APIs in mind. So, how should we handle cases where it's not a Google APIKey but a different API?

Comment: You should not put any secret information on the client side in this case mobile app.
For example, I put my secret key from open chat API on my own backend implementation.
So I could use the open chat API without exposing the secret key.  And I also can make custom auth on my backend to make it more secure.

Comment: I see. You use a backend (Node.js or TypeScript)!

Comment: I added more explanation about this.